# flutter - DateTime.now() not same in my local time

Tags: datetime, time, dart, flutter

I have a case to check the store opening-closed hours.
Im solve this using the code below:

```
final _openHours = 09;
final _openMinute = 00;
final _closeHours = 15;
final _closeMinute = 00;

var now = DateTime.now();
print(now);

var _open = new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, _openHours, _openMinute, now.second);
var _close = new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, _closeHours, _closeMinute, now.second);

now.isAfter(_open) && now.isBefore(_close) {
  print("online");  
} else {
  print("offline");
}
```

but when I print `DateTime.now()`, this time does not match the current time?
I have tried it using manually input currently time to make sure the code checks the opening and closing hours, and its works.

Comment: `DateTime.now` should return an instant in time anchored in the local time zone of the host. Is it running on a server?

Comment: @jspcal Yeah i think so, no.. just locally.
the difference is a few hours

Comment: Are you running in an emulator? Is the device in the emulator set to a different timezone? Does `print(DateTime.now().timeZoneName);` look correct to you?

Comment: well, I forgot setup emulators date settings

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, this waste me lot of time, I answer it to help someone may encounter same problem.
After modify emulator settings, it work OK.
[image]

Comment: You may need to turn on "Set time automatically" as well as the emulator may not have the right time.