# Flutter on Android emulator showing incorrect DateTime.now()

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, android-emulator

Emulator timezone is the same as system timezone, but Flutter's `DateTime.now()` is returning GMT time.

The greeting in the below code should've been 'Good afternoon'. Local time is `15:23`.
[image: Android Emulator showing Flutter demo code]

---

**Details:**

Flutter/Dart:

> flutter --version
> Flutter 2.0.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> Framework • revision 4d7946a68d (12 days ago) • 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
> Engine • revision 3459eb2436
> Tools • Dart 2.12.2

Emulator:

> Nexus 5X on Android 7.0 (Nougat) - API 24
> Emulator version: 30.5.3-7196367

System:

> Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
> 10.0.15063 Build 15063

VS Code:

> Version: 1.54.3 (user setup)
> Electron: 11.3.0
> Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
> Node.js: 12.18.3
> V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.15063

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64237067/15106159

Comment: @Anna: I already tried that. The emulator timezone is correct as you can see the time in the phone's status bar on top is `15:23` matching my system time, but the time inside the app is `09:51`.

Comment: Tried the exact code and working fine in Emulators

Comment: @MidhunMP: Thanks, I picked up the hint that I should try a different emulator. It worked! Check my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the bug is particular to the `Nexus 5X Android 7.0 Nougat` emulator, and the code runs fine on `Pixel 3a Android 11` emulator.

Here is the same code on both emulators side-by-side. Local time is `16:37`, GMT time is `11:07` at the time of this screenshot. Both emulators are already set to the same timezone as the system.
[image: Android emulators for Flutter]

Comment: Encountered this today.  Restarting the emulator from cold boot loaded the correct date.